# OnItemClickListener crash the app

Tags: android, carousel, onclicklistener

```
I'm working with carousel i just used the Caruosel source code from [codeProject][1] site
```

every thing worked good until i added the setOnItemClickListener func when i run the app it's crashing how can i solve this crash to make my app work???

```
import com.name.w.R;
    import com.name.controls.Carousel;
    import com.name.controls.CarouselAdapter;
    import com.name.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;

    public class NameActivity extends Activity  {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */


        Carousel care;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           care=(Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);


            care.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
             public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
                    Toast.makeText(NameActivity.this, "Position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();               
                }





            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You know..a logcat error output would be very nice ;)

Comment: hope you are using the latest carousel code from http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/source/browse/

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1117): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.name.w/com.name.w.NameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)E/AndroidRuntime(1117): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.name.w.NameActivity.onCreate(NameActivity.java:28)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya no i didnt use this code I used the code in the link above and which i mad is that i copied the classes in classes in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find view by ID is returning null. Please do a check for null after the below line.

```
care = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    if (care != null) {
        care.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(NameActivity.this, "Position=" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ya it's work but why it's empty the carousel should'nt be empty plz if u can help to make it full ?? cause i used xml file to fill ?

Comment: Check the main.xml file for the id "carousel" and also check its type...whether it is a carousel or not

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.name.w"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"...>
 <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="5dip"
android:gravity="top" android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="550dp"> <com.name.controls.Carousel android:layout_width="fill_parent"android:layout_height="fill_parent"android:id="@+id/carousel"  pj:UseReflection="true"
pj:Items="@array/entries" pj:SelectedItem="0" android:animationDuration="200"/>

Comment: I just added the main xml every thing is Right in the code I'm sry for the asking but plz if u know sth to help??

Comment: @loleana I'm not able to find any issues with the layout. Are you sure this is the layout which is using over there? Do you have any other main.xml file in any other folders "layout-xlarge, layout-land etc". Please make sure of it. Also try removing the other properties of the carousel, please set only the height, width and id and check first.

Comment: I checked all of these things all is correct :( im really confused of this problem

Comment: Try cleaning your project, deleting the gen folder and try running again.

Comment: you will find arrays.xml in values add your drawables in that xml it will populate your carousel

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya I just added them the photos appear in a curousel but does'nt make any action when click on it <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <array name="entries">
  <item>@drawable/ramadan_04</item>  
  <item>@drawable/ramadan_07</item>   
  <item>@drawable/ramadan_09</item>  
  <item>@drawable/ram</item>
  
       
 </array> 
    
</resources>

Comment: I told you earlier get the updated code from the link I posted earlier.

Comment: could not download it from the link it gaves me not found when try to download it by svn